# How to add search functionality to my listview?

Tags: android, listview, search, filter, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying without success to add search functionality to my images listview.
Can you help me?
What i have to add to adapter and fragment in order to do it?

My code below:

```
public class Fragment2 extends SherlockFragment {

DatabaseConnector dbConnector;
private Cursor cursor;
private ListView listView; 
private EditText inputSearch; 
ImageCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

    dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(view.getContext());
    dbConnector.open();
    cursor = dbConnector.getPlaces("");

    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv);
    inputSearch = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    adapter = new ImageCursorAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.listview_each_item, cursor, new String [] { "title", "description", "picture"}, new int[] {  R.id.title, R.id.msg, R.id.pic });
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence arg0) {
            dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(view.getContext());
            dbConnector.open();
            cursor = dbConnector.getPlaces(arg0.toString());
            dbConnector.close();
            return cursor;
        }
    });
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    dbConnector.close();

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });  
    return view;
}
```

}

Asapter:

```
public class ImageCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private Cursor c;

private Context context;

String title;
String desc;
String pic;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.c = c;
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = inView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_each_item, null);
    }
    this.c.moveToPosition(pos);      
    title = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("title"));
    desc = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("description"));
    pic = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("picture"));
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    if(pic != "")
    {
        try {

            String file_ = pic.replace("file:///", "");
            int size = 30;
            File f = new File(file_);
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(f,60,80);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.marker_green72);
    }
    TextView tv_title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tv_title.setText(title);
    TextView tv_desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
    tv_desc.setText(desc);
    return(v);
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    return bmp;
}


public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
            scale*=2;
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

}

I would appreciate an answer that includes repair to my code.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you don't need a separate EditText view and addTextChangedListener, also there is no need for a custom adapter

Comment: all you need is setTextFilterEnabled(true), just open your keyboard and start typing

Comment: Unfortunately your advice did not solve צט problemץ

Comment: why not?  it's a build-in mechanism of list filtering

Comment: I do not know why not, that's why I asked for help. What do I need to change in the code to make it work? Can you send me a revised code?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have an edit text its a whole lot easier , forget the other answers , I've been through the same lot as your through right now .

Firstly , identify the edit text for ex edit text a;

Then add a text watcher to it and carry out the filtering in ontextchanged.

Well, I'm on mobile and its too tough to type so you can just contact me at avrsaditya@gmail.com , give me a chance ill  help you , if satisfied choose me as best answer , well I have a lot of sample code

And you might be interested of integrating to your action bar too

Comment: I sent you my email address.